# Window.print result from ng2-pdfjs-viewer is different on Chrome and IE11

Tags: angular, pdf, internet-explorer-11, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

We generate PDFs and show in Chrome and IE11 with the ng2-pdfjs-viewer component. Both of them show the same results and it's fine. 
But when we try to print documents, results of printing are different: after Chrome the resulting document looks the same as visible PDF, but in IE11 the resulting document content is shrunked (scaled down). 
We finished fixing the problem with updating viewer.css for IE. It there some right way to fix the problem without updates of ng2-pdfjs-viewer code ?

Comment: I check the ng2-pdfjs-viewer documentation but did not got any information regarding this issue. It can be possible that new IE security update caused this issue in IE which get fix by updating the viewer.css. You did not inform us which exact version of ng2-pdfjs-viewer you are using for making test. I suggest you to make a test with the latest version may help to avoid this issue. Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer

Comment: We tested it with the 3.4.8 version, this is the latest one. Due to privacy reason  I can't show real documents here, but the difference in print contents is obvious

Comment: You can submit your feedback for ng2-pdfjs-viewer library on their official site. They can test the issue with their library. As it is a third party library, Issue cannot be fixed from IE side.

Comment: Thank you, I opened an issue there (GitHub): https://github.com/intbot/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/issues/33

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - This is the author of this package. Is it possible to create a SO tag with  ng2-pdfjs-viewer? I may have seen this question early is it had. As stated in the issue created, Mozilla's PDFJS and viewer does support IE with limitations, hence it should be directly reported to them. Please see their FAQ - Which browsers are supported here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Comment: My bad. Looks like the tag is already there. :-)

Comment: @int-i, Thanks for providing the information about the cause for this issue. if possible for you than can you please post it as an answer? It can help other community members who have similar kind of questions in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla's PDFJS and viewer does NOT fully support IE. There are many limitations.
It is also stated in their FAQ.

Which browsers are supported Quention in following link: [FAQ](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

Content pasted here for easy access
"IE 11/Edge -> Mostly supported -> Some missing features/defects have been reported, but no problems in general."